# Local notification flutter :Error "Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'show' was called on null."

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification

**How i can create notification without click button?
how to initialize when opening the application a notification appears ?**

```
 String groupKey = 'com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL';
    String groupChannelId = 'grouped channel id';
    String groupChannelName = 'grouped channel name';
    String groupChannelDescription = 'grouped channel description';
    AndroidNotificationDetails firstNotificationAndroidSpecifics =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
      groupChannelId, groupChannelName,
      groupChannelDescription,
      importance: Importance.Max,
      priority: Priority.High,
      groupKey: groupKey,
      style: AndroidNotificationStyle.BigText,

      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
    );
    final AndroidNotificationDetails android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'ch_ID',
      'Ch_Name',
      'ch_Description',
      priority: Priority.High,
      importance: Importance.Max,

      // add this line in your code
      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(''),
    );
    NotificationDetails firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics =
    NotificationDetails(
      firstNotificationAndroidSpecifics, null,);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        1, 'Confirmation ',
        'Hello' , firstNotificationPlatformSpecifics);
```

how to launch a notification in flutter?